# Access token differs between Website with Facebook Login and Native Android App?

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I'm creating an app for a website that works with Facebook login. We have a database in which all access tokens are stored. What I want to do is compare the access tokens from our database to the access token that is granted when you use the Facebook login button of the app. However, both access tokens seem to differ for the same user.

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

If it is normal, is there a workaround? I can do validation using just the userId, but that seems very insecure.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mats Raemen, May you please answer my question whether the web service and use the access_token obtained by the android native application? We are implementing a web service application and have not found a good way to authenticate the user on Android app. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is compare the access tokens from our database to the access token that is granted when you use the Facebook login button of the app. However, both access tokens seem to differ for the same user.

That is totally normal – because access tokens expire, and then on next login a new one might be issued.

> I can do validation using just the userId, but that seems very insecure.

First of all, *what exactly* do you want to “validate” …?

Comment: I want to validate whether the user has an account in our database since you cannot register through the app, but only login.

Comment: Then don’t make that connection based on an access token, but on the Facebook user id instead.

Comment: It's not a very safe option to base user validation on a parameter that is publicly known. Solved it however by passing the access token to a webservice which in its place looks up the user id and validates that.

Comment: I usually use the signed_request parameter for that. Since it’s signed with the app secret, that only I and Facebook know, I think there’s little way of manipulating that.

Comment: +1 for the comment that suggests using a signed_request parameter